# near "alias": syntax error VHDL compiling

Tags: vhdl, test-bench

I am trying to compile a test bench that use alias. This testbench is compiled in VHDL2008 but

```
alias reg_test is << signal dut.i_dut_int.extra_signal : std_logic >>;
```

returns:

> * Error: near "alias": syntax error

where ever i put this line.

What is the problem?

Comment: This is not a (minimal) complete verifiable example. We cannot reproduce your issue this way, thus cannot help you.

Comment: Since alias is spelled correctly.  My guess is the line prior to it is either missing a semicolon or is the source of the error.    Remember a compiler gives an error message where it dies - What it is saying here is that I found the word "alias" and now I am so confused that I must stop.

Comment: I notice you are using a relative path for your path to "extra_signal".   This means the instance of the DUT is in the testbench - hence, I need to ask, did you declare your alias in the architecture or process? It needs to be in a process if it is not already.   The object referenced in an external name must be elaborated before the external name is elaborated.